# Chrome Extension Content Script - Inject Javascript before page code

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to make a Chrome extension with a content script to inject a script into a webpage *before all other scripts in the page*. (I am using the [xhook](https://github.com/jpillora/xhook) library to intercept XHR requests, which overwrites the XHR class. I need to do this because it is currently [impossible to modify responses using Chrome extension APIs](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=104058).) The "document_start" event is executed before any of the DOM is written, so I manually create the body element with the content script. However, this creates 2 body tags in the HTML, which appears to make variables defined within the injected script tag inaccessible to the code in the main page.

How should I do this?

I have simplified version of my code below:

**manifest.json**

```
{
    // Required
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "My Extension",
    "version": "0.1",
    "description": "My Description",
    "author": "Me",
    "permissions": ["https://example.com/*"],
    "content_scripts": [{
            "matches": ["https://example.com/*"],
            "js": ["xhook.js"],
            "run_at": "document_start",
            "all_frames": true
        }
    ]
}
```

**xhook.js**

```js
var script_tag = document.createElement('script');
script_tag.type = 'text/javascript';
holder = document.createTextNode(`

//Xhook library code
// XHook - v1.4.9 - https://github.com/jpillora/xhook
//...

//Now to use the library
console.log('loading extension');
xhook.after(function (request, response) {
    //console.log(request.url);
    if (request.url.startsWith("https://example.com/")) {
        var urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
        fetch('https://example.com/robots.txt')
        .then(
            function (apiresponse) {
            if (apiresponse.status == 200) {
                response.text = apiresponse.text();
                return;
            };
            if (apiresponse.status !== 200) {
                console.log('File not found. Status Code: ' +
                    apiresponse.status);
                return;
            };
        });
    };
});
xhook.enable();`);
script_tag.appendChild(holder);
document.body = document.createElement("body");
document.head.appendChild(script_tag);
```

Thanks!

Comment: 1) Don't create body, simply append the script to document.documentElement since DOM spec has no restrictions on its children. 2) Hooking is just a couple of lines of code so you probably don't need an entire library, 3) Currently you're polluting the global page namespace with a `xhook` variable - move it inside an IIFE if you really want to use xhook.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thank you! This mostly worked for me to inject the JS and intercept the XHR responses. Is there any way to rename the real `load` event so I can intercept the response before raising `load` on the rest of the document?

Comment: I wrote a new question for the event interception: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55270830/intercepted-xhr-run-function-before-raising-load

Answer (score 0):

If the extension is loaded at `document_start`, `document.head = null`. Hence, to overcome this, do - `document.lastChild.appendChild(script_tag);`. This creates a script tag in your `<html>` hierarchy. Hope this helps.

Also, Could you please tell why are you doing the following statement
    `document.body = document.createElement("body");` I believe this is not required.