# Intercepted XHR - run function before raising load

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest

On a web page with a extension-injected custom `XMLHttpRequest` class, I need to intercept and modify certain responses *before* the `load` event is raised on the rest of the document. Right now, my modification code reacts to the load event. How would I use a function to modify the response before the `load` event was fired?

This is the code I am using:

```js
let oldXHROpen = window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;
window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function (method, url, async, user, password) {
    var originalresp = this;
    //Do something with the method, url and etc.
    originalresp.addEventListener('load', async function () {
        //Do something with the response text
        //***This function needs to execute before load is raised for the rest of the document***
        value = '<note><body>This is a test XML document.</body></note>';
        parser = new DOMParser();
        apiresponsexml = parser.parseFromString(value, 'application/xml');
        //Replace data in the response
        Object.defineProperties(originalresp, {
            'response': {
                value: value
            },
            'responseXML': {
                value: apiresponsexml,
            },
            'responseText': {
                value: value,
            }
        });
    });
    return oldXHROpen.apply(originalresp, arguments);
};
```

This question is a continuation of [this previous thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55244963/chrome-extension-content-script-inject-javascript-before-page-code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override `onreadystatechange` (fired before load/onload) inside `send()`:

```
function plantXhrHook() {
  let origStateChange;

  function modifyResponse(e) {
    if (this.readyState === 4) {
      const value = 'foo';
      let xml;
      Object.defineProperties(this, {
        response: {value},
        responseText: {value},
        responseXML: {
          get() {
            if (typeof xml === 'undefined')
              xml = new DOMParser().parseFromString(value, 'application/xml');
            return xml;
          },
        },
      });
    }
    if (origStateChange) {
      origStateChange.apply(this, arguments);
    }
  };

  const origSend = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send;
  XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = function () {
    origStateChange = this.onreadystatechange;
    this.onreadystatechange = modifyResponse;
    origSend.apply(this, arguments);
  };
}

const script = document.createElement('script');
script.textContent = `(${plantXhrHook})()`;
document.documentElement.appendChild(script);
script.remove();
```

Since other extensions or page scripts may also hook XHR, it would make sense to run your code in a content script with ["run_at": "document_start"](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#run_time).

Comment: Thanks! I'll give this a try when I have more time to add in my other code.